# Intercepting PHP traffic

Tags: networking, apache2, php

I would like to know how feasible it is (and then the ability to stop) someone running malicious code on a Ubuntu server that reads the data sent to, and handled by PHP (I am using the apache module not Fastcgi).

Lets assume my form does a standard `$_POST` over SSL. The traffic will hit the Port >> Apache >> PHP. I want to make sure that were someone to get access to the server (even a malicious employee) they wouldn't be able to read the traffic getting to PHP as I assume by that point it is decrypted?

So 2 questions in one - how feasible is an attack like that and how could it be stopped? Are there privileges that could be set to restrict access to read traffic hitting PHP? (For example if you'd have to have root permissions that's fine as the default user doesn't have them).

(I have looked up questions relating to packet-sniffing but am more concerned with internal server traffic rather than network traffic)

(I also appreciate that were a hacker to have access to the server that isn't great! I'm talking hypothetically to try and rule out options)

Comment: I'd start by checking [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/how-can-i-sanitize-user-input-with-php).

Comment: Thanks @KGIII however this assumes that the data is polluted. It might simply be valid but a username or details that you wouldn't want exposed to internal access on a server.

Answer (score 0):

Anything you do on your server to secure it can be discovered and undone by someone with physical access.

This is a losing battle. Restrict physical access.